# How to store a mapping between a type A and a run-time Func<A,B> type transformation?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, code-generation, linq-expressions

### Runtime Mapping objects of type A into a similar type A`

1. List of types is discovered run-time using `System.Reflection`
2. An expression `Expression<Func<object, object>>` is made for each appropriate `Type`. The function converts object of type `oldType` into an object of `newType`.

---

**Sidenote:**

The generic type arguments for the `Func<object, object>` are somewhat-misleading, it *feels* like it should be `Func<newType,oldType>`, but the types are not known compile-time:

```
Expression<Func<object, object>>  GetConvertExpression(Type oldType, Type newType)
```

---

3. The expressions are compiled and stored into a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>`

---

### Question - How to solve the downsides of the current approach?

1. A dictionary lookup is necessary to convert an object.  I had thought of *baking* in a big `if/then/else` or `case` statment into a big *unified* `Expression`, this could work well with a small number of types.
2. Unnecessary casting operations within the generated `IL`.
3. Argument and return type of the generated code is of type `object`. This basically *ensures* that there will be casting operations all around. Especially when a large transformation of `List<oldType>` to `List<newType>` has to be performed.

---

Generated code from the `Expression`:

```
object convert(object oldInst)
{
    newType newInst = newType();
    oldType oldInstCast = (oldType)oldInst;
    newInst.field1 = oldInstCast.field1;
    .......
    // note: if some field of oldInst has a type in the DICTIONARY and
    //       it's value is not null, we have to perform the convert
    //       operation recursively for that field
    if(oldInstCast.field3 != null)
    {
        // Type of the field was determined when this code was generated
        // And it is known that the dictionary will contain it
        Func<object, object> transformFun = dictionary[oldFieldType];
        newInst.field3 = (newFieldType)transformFun(oldInstCast.field3);
    }

    newInst.fieldz = oldInstCast.fieldz;

    return newInst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I wrote the original answer at around midnight. I think it shows. It sounds like what you need most are how to construct the delegate when the parameter and return types are only known at runtime. You get around this problem by using `object`. You can still do it strongly typed. The most relevant calls are:

```
Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(A), typeof(NewA));
```

This creates the delegate type `Func<A, NewA>` as for converting from `A` to `NewA`. To create an `Expression<Func<A, NewA>>` when `A` and `NewA` aren't necessarily known at compile time, you can use this overload of [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350515(v=vs.110).aspx).

Previous answer:

---

Excellent question. I had fun trying to draw up a solution with stronger typing.

I did a mockup of this and I see no reason you can't generate expressions of type `Expression<Func<TOld, TNew>>` instead of `Expression<Func<object, object>>`. You wouldn't need casting inside of those conversion functions. However, I'm still not sure it's a better solution. Here's what I came up with so far:

The meat of the conversion/reflection/expression code is in a class I called ConverterDictionary, which builds these converters then holds them in a dictionary, and offers them up in a nicely typed way. I'm guessing that 95% of this is non-material for you since it sounds like you already figured out the reflection and expression-building portions of your problem. Everything else is 100% sample code.

Let me know what needs clarification or further explanation, or what could be more helpful.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cv = new ConverterDictionary();
        var type2_converter = cv.GetConverter<Type2, Type2_New>();
        var converterF = type2_converter.Compile();
        var type2 = new Type2 { Field1 = "Hello", Field2 = "World" };
        var type2_New = converterF(type2);
    }
}

public class ConverterDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, object> conversionDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, object>();
    public ConverterDictionary()
    {
        var convertPairs = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(ClassConvertAttribute)))
            .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t, (Type)(t.CustomAttributes.First().NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.Value)))
            .ToList();
        foreach(var pair in convertPairs)
        {
            var fromType = pair.Item1;
            var toType = pair.Item2;
            var fieldConversions = fromType.GetFields()
                .Where(f => f.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(FieldConvertAttribute)))
                .Select(f => Tuple.Create(f, toType.GetField((string)(f.CustomAttributes.First().NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.Value))))
                .ToList();
            var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(fromType, toType);
            var param1 = Expression.Parameter(fromType, "oldInst");
            var returnVar = Expression.Variable(toType, "newInst");
            var expr = Expression.Lambda(
                delegateType,
                Expression.Block(
                    new ParameterExpression[] { returnVar },
                    new Expression[]
                    {
                        Expression.Assign(
                            returnVar,
                            Expression.New(toType)
                        ),
                    }.Concat(
                        fieldConversions.Select(fc => 
                            Expression.Assign(
                                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                                    returnVar,
                                    fc.Item2
                                ),
                                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                                    param1,
                                    fc.Item1
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ).Concat(
                       new Expression[] { returnVar }
                    )
                ),
                param1
            );
            conversionDict[pair] = expr;
        }
    }

    public Expression<Func<TFrom, TTo>> GetConverter<TFrom, TTo>()
    {
        var key = Tuple.Create(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo));
        if (conversionDict.ContainsKey(key))
            return conversionDict[key] as Expression<Func<TFrom, TTo>>;
        return null;
    }
}

[ClassConvert(ToType=typeof(Type1_New))]
public class Type1
{
    [FieldConvert(ToFieldName = "Field1")]
    public string Field1;
}

[ClassConvert(ToType = typeof(Type2_New))]
public class Type2
{
    [FieldConvert(ToFieldName="Field1")]
    public string Field1;

    [FieldConvert(ToFieldName = "Field2_New")]
    public string Field2;
}

public class Type1_New
{
    public string Field1;
}

public class Type2_New
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2_New;
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class ClassConvertAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ToType { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FieldConvertAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ToFieldName { get; set; }
}
```